# Handling Graphs of Managed Object Proxies to Unmanaged Objects

Tags: .net, pinvoke

My question is similar to this one: [Managing destructors of managed (C#) and unmanaged (C++) objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943830/managing-destructors-of-managed-c-and-unmanaged-c-objects)

But with a twist.

I have, essentially, an object graph, or hierarchy, where class `Foo` owns some references to multiple instances of class `Bar` (etc.)

In .NET I have a managed representation of `Foo` which maintains an `IntPtr` to the real `Foo` and uses P/Invoke to call methods on the real `Foo` (acting as a proxy).

My managed implementation of `Foo` (the proxy) implements `IDisposable`.

The proxy `Foo` contains a readonly property of type `List<Bar>`.

My managed `Bar` proxy works the same way (holds unto an `IntPtr` for the real `Bar` it represents).

When the real `Foo` is released, it releases all of it's children (including all `Bar`s).

What is the best approach for dealing with this scenario - as I don't want managed clients of the `Foo` proxy to get a hold of a reference to a `Bar` and keep it around longer than they do their reference to the `Foo` proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just implemented a simple reference counting scheme.

I was hoping there would be some other way, but, at the end of the day, it was simple, and was really the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm over-simplifiying this, but your `Bar` (proxy) class should have a `Dispose` method that is called by the parent/owner `Foo` class.  And like many classes, once the `Bar` object has been disposed it should set an internal `m_disposed` flag to true and throw an `ObjectDisposed` exception if any of its methods are used afterward.  You shouldn't care if the client has a reference to the managed `Bar` object as long as its internal unmanaged resources have been cleaned up.

Comment: The problem I had with this solution is that you imply a parent/child relationship between the `Bar` and `Foo` proxies which doesn't exist. Because I don't know when the underlying `List<Bar>` items change, I'm creating new managed proxy classes each time the `List<Bar>` property is called. Keeping references in `Foo` to each `Bar` which was ever created isn't workable (this list could grow to millions of instances).

Comment: Perhaps I misundestood this "I have, essentially, an object graph, or hierarchy, where class Foo owns some references to multiple instances of class Bar (etc.)" ...doesn't own imply  that not imply a parent/child?

Comment: In **unmanaged** land, yes, `Foo` owns several `Bar`s. But in **managed** land, I'm creating new `Bar` proxies every time the List is retrieved.

Comment: You should probably know - I already solved my problem by implemented a reference counting scheme. I was simply hoping someone may have had some other idea. But, honestly, there is no way I could have gotten around reference counting. I've simplified this question, but in reality, the problem is more complicated - and even ignoring the problem I posted about here I needed the reference counting.